# How do i extract XML tags/entity with the same name?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, tags

as u can see from my xml, it has two pineapple, and i wanna extract its value. I am very new to python hope u can help me!

```
-<csData>
-<entity name="1" parentEntity="123" type='a'>

<attribute name="ab" value = ""/>

**<attribute name="pineapple" value = "0.9099"/>**

<attribute name="ac" value = ""/>

-<entity name="0" parentEntity="234" type='a'>

<attribute name="ab" value = ""/>

**<attribute name="pineapple" value = "0.2881"/>**

<attribute name="ac" value = ""/>
</csData>
```

So here i wanna extract PINEAPPLE's value and here it the code i have :

```
def extract_pineapple(self, cd, cs, pineapple, root):
  data = {'cd_id': cd_id, 'cs_id'=cs=id}
  for c in root.findall("./csData/entity[@type='a']"):
     for attr in c.findall("./attribute[@name:'pineapple']:
         data['pineapple'] = c.find("./attribute[@name='pineapple'].get('value')
return [data]
```

OUTPUT :
It only extracted one value :
pineapple : 0.2881
pineapple : 0.2881

what i want is :
pineapple: 0.2881
pineapple: 0.9099

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<csData>
<entity name="1" parentEntity="123" type="a"/>

<attribute name="ab" value = ""/>

<attribute name="pineapple" value = "0.9099"/>

<attribute name="ac" value = "" />

<entity name="0" parentEntity="234" type="a"/>

<attribute name="ab" value = ""/>

<attribute name="pineapple" value = "0.2881"/>

<attribute name="ac" value = ""/>
</csData>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
values = [e.attrib['value'] for e in root.findall('.//attribute[@name="pineapple"]')]
print(values)
```

output

```
['0.9099', '0.2881']
```